# How to get value from multiple input fields which are inside a for loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one input field inside a for loop. I am populating the value from a database to that input field so that the input field is populated multiple times. Now the problem is that I couldn't get those values in codeigniter. Below is the code so that you can understand easily.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($skilldetails);$i++)
 {
        // print_r($skilldetails);
        $skillvalue=$skilldetails[$i]['skillname'];
        $skill=array(
                'name'=>'editskill[]',
                'placeholder'=>'Skill',
                'class'=>'skills_text col-md-10 form-control autocomplete',
                'id'=>'skill',
                'value'=>$skillvalue
            );
        echo form_input($skill); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code will not produce unique id for the input fields. `Id` should be unique. You can do this way.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($skilldetails);$i++)
{
    // print_r($skilldetails);
    $skillvalue=$skilldetails[$i]['skillname'];
    $skill=array(
            'name'=>'editskill[]',
            'placeholder'=>'Skill',
            'class'=>'skills_text col-md-10 form-control autocomplete',
            'id'=>'skill_'.$i,
            'value'=>$skillvalue
        );
    echo form_input($skill); 
 }
```

Now your question's answer is you can get it input after form submit like this way

```
 $skills=$this->input->post('editskill');//if you submitting form using post method
 //$this->input->get('editskill');if get method
```

Now `$skills` is the array of your inputs.you can use `foreach`,`for` loops on it.`$skills[0]` is your first input value.

Comment: @Islam thank you , I tried your code it showing undefined variable in forloop , iam using for loop to display the value

Comment: use this way `foreach($skills as $skill){echo $skill;}` or `for($i=0;$i<count($skills);$i++){echo $skills[$i];}`